# How can i execute this code in python?

Tags: python, curl

curl https://api.smartsheet.com/1.1/sheet/7846568935090052 -H "Authorization: Bearer 4ziycpnqjvto49oah6t6urd4un" -H "Accept: application/vnd.ms-excel" -o  output.xls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module:

```
subprocess.call('curl https://api.smartsheet.com/1.1/sheet/7846568935090052 -H "Authorization: Bearer 4ziycpnqjvto49oah6t6urd4un" -H "Accept: application/vnd.ms-excel" -o output.xls')
```

Alternatively, you could use the older [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) way:

```
os.system('curl https://api.smartsheet.com/1.1/sheet/7846568935090052 -H "Authorization: Bearer 4ziycpnqjvto49oah6t6urd4un" -H "Accept: application/vnd.ms-excel" -o output.xls')
```